# Configurable Products Import Issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, product-import

I am trying to upload this CSV file for the configurable products.

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yJBI_rS7miln6yATN6TYgoh3H4RSyty4WKJI9zNz1aw/edit?usp=sharing

Unfortunately, the error I'm facing is

> **1. Column configurable_variations: Attribute with code "sizechanged" does not exist or is missing from product attribute set in a row(s): 2**

However, when I checked my `additional_attributes` and `configurable_variations` attributes, it seems like I got all of the definition of the attribute there already.

I hope someone please have a look into the file and helps me with the answer.
Much appreciate it.

Comment: Please do first row for configurable products than set simple products. and check with your attributes and attribute set.

Comment: Hi Anas, thanks for your reply, well I made it first row but it still gives me the same error. 
And about the attribute stuffs, is it true that if i have sizeChanged in addtional_attributes, I would not have to do anything with the settings from admin panel ?

Comment: No, in admin panel don't have any settings for that.

Comment: Yes, I got that I might be supposed to go to the attribute set from the stores option at the sidebar, I meant since the sizeChanged attr is a part of addtional_attributes column, I don't believe that I should change something with the attribute set right ?
I am still a newbie in Magento 2 so sorry if I said something wrong.